# how to avoid duplicate insert to SQLite

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

SQLite always inserts duplicate row even when I query the existing rows before inserting.

To avoid duplicate inserting rows, I queried the existing rows first

```
// avoid duplicate inserting request
private boolean isRowDuplicate(Avatar avatar) {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            AVATAR_TABLE_NAME,
            projection,
            AVATAR_COLUMN_SIGNATURE
            + "=? and " + AVATAR_COLUMN_URL + "=?",
            new String[] { avatar.getSignature(), avatar.getUrl()},
            null,   // don't group the rows
            null,   // don't filter by row groups
            null    // The sort order
            );
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        cursor.close();
        return true;   
    }
    cursor.close();
    return false;

}
```

then only new rows can be inserted

```
public void saveAvatars(List<Avatar> avatars) {

    List<Avatar> validAvatars = Lists.newArrayList();

    // query database in case insert duplicate rows
    for (Avatar avatar : avatars) {
        if (!isRowDuplicate(avatar)) {
            validAvatars.add(avatar);
        }
    }

    for (Avatar avatar : validAvatars) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(AVATAR_COLUMN_SIGNATURE, avatar.getSignature());
        values.put(AVATAR_COLUMN_URL, avatar.getUrl());
        values.put(AVATAR_COLUMN_MTIME, avatar.getMtime());
        /*values.put(AVATAR_COLUMN_IS_DEFAULT, (avatar.isIs_default() ? 1 : 0));*/
        database.insert(AVATAR_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I run the app, clear all cache data, I still can find duplicate rows inserted. I got confused about this.

Please be noticed that I called database operations in a child thread, so I wonder if it caused by multithread and how to fix that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you create your database, add **UNIQUE** keyword in order to avoid duplicate. See this link: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Answer (score 1):

`moveToFirst()` goes to the first record (if it exists).
The following `moveToNext()` call then goes to the second record (if it exists).

You would have to check the return value of the `moveToFirst()` call.

And instead of fiddling around with a cursor, you could just count the rows directly:

```java
long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(
                    database,
                    AVATAR_TABLE_NAME,
                    AVATAR_COLUMN_SIGNATURE + "=? and " +
                    AVATAR_COLUMN_URL + "=?",
                    new String[] { avatar.getSignature(), avatar.getUrl()});
return count > 0;
```

Comment: But I still don\`t know how to adopt this to my problem